# Could not get unknown property 'armeabi' for object of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.NdkOptions

Tags: android, cmake, android-ndk

```
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags ""
            }
        }
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true

        ndk {
            abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'x86', 'x86_64', 'arm64-v8a' 'armeabi'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
           path "CMakeLists.txt"
        }
   }
}
```

i want abiFilters support `'armeabi-v7a', 'x86', 'x86_64', 'arm64-v8a' 'armeabi'`  。
But `armeabi` is always not recognized.

if only support " 'armeabi-v7a', 'x86', 'x86_64', 'arm64-v8a' " is OK;
if only support armeabi  is OK;

But not all support;

Comment: Note that since the latest NDK release (r17) _"Support for ARMv5 (armeabi), MIPS, and MIPS64 has been removed. Attempting to build any of these ABIs will result in an error."_

Answer (score 1):

You should use an [older version of NDK](https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/older_releases) if you desperately need `armeabi`. But I doubt that you really need it, the devices with ARM chips that don't support `armeabi-v7a` have not been produced since 2012.